Energy shift in generalized BCS Theory
I'd like to understand the constant energy shift in the (generalized) mean-field theory of superconductivity.
Consider a system with the Hamiltonian $$H= \sum_k \epsilon_{k\sigma} c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma} - \sum_{k,k'}\sum_{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} V_{k,k'}^{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} c_{k,s_1}^\dagger c_{-k,s_2}^\dagger c_{-k',s_3}c_{k',s_4}. $$
After a mean-field decomposition with the gap matrix $\Delta_{s_1 s_2}(k) = - \sum_{k'}\sum_{s_3,s_4} V_{k,k'}^{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} c_{-k',s_3}c_{k',s_4} $, we have:
$$H_{MF} = \sum_k \epsilon_{k\sigma} c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma} + \sum_{k,s_1,s_2} \Delta(k)_{s_1 s_2} c_{k,s_1}^\dagger c_{-k,s_2}^\dagger  +  + \sum_{k,s_1,s_2} \Delta(k)_{s_1 s_2}^* c_{-k,s_1} c_{k,s_2} + \sum_{k,k'}\sum_{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} V_{k,k'}^{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} \langle c_{k,s_1}^\dagger c_{-k,s_2}^\dagger \rangle \langle c_{-k',s_3}c_{k',s_4} \rangle.$$
My question is about the last term. I know that, in a simple case (ex., singlet superconductor with $k-$independent interaction), the last term can be written simply as $\Delta^2/g$ where $g$ is the interaction strength. In more general scenarios, I have seen this term simplified by plugging in the self-consistency equation for $\Delta$.
I am wondering: In general, how can you simplify the last term without appealing to the self-consistency conditions? For example, say I have a separable (but not singlet) interaction. Is there a known simplification in that case? Or do I just have to check case-by-case?
Thanks so much!
